# What does this c/++ code do?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, printf

I have no clue of what this complex code does or how it works please explain.
All I know is \t is tab and \b is backspace. I just don't understand the ;; in the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  for (;;) {
  printf(" \t\b\b\b\b\b\b");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: "What does this c/++ code do?"  Nothing useful.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It causes a Windows XP or NT machine to blue screen:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/microsoft.public.vc.language/VnuU_EpDQ7Y/7TAcZaAnVWAJ

On other systems, it's just an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

well its an infinate loop `for(;;)` could be written as `while(true)` usually you'd have a range in it `for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i);`

Sometimes you might see `for(int i = 0; i < 4;) { ++i; }`

That prints a `space`, then a tab `\t`, and then backspace's `\b` six times.

Unsure what the outcome of that is.

Comment: Thanks that answers it guess I am to used to for(int I =0; true; I++)

Comment: And if you think about that the `int i` and incrementing it is useless if neither the condition or the loop content uses `i`... then everything should be clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you know what does `\t` and `\b`, it will run an infinite loop of printing `\t` and `\b` as listed in statement  `printf(" \t\b\b\b\b\b\b");`